# Simulate enter key in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to let jquery press the enter for me when the page loads. I already tried a few things, but they did not work. I would rather not use any plugins. So what i want is that jquery puts the focus on my input field and presses enter. This is my current code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#test').focus().trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 13 });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`jQuery.Event constructor`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)**

```js
$('body').on('keypress', function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
});

// Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress", {
  which: 13
});

// trigger an artificial keypress event with which 13
jQuery("body").trigger(e);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your on load function/ready function

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 13;  
$('#test').focus();
 $("#test").trigger(e);
```